# sql server replication - get last synchronization date from query

Tags: sql, sql-server, synchronization, replication

Does anyone know the query the last synchronization date from sql server (2008).

It is the same information displayed in replication monitor, but I want to be able to get that date from a query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see a lot of info about merge sessions by using the system table msMerge_sessions:

```
select * from msMerge_sessions
```

Depending on the info you need, use the other system tables available in your database.

Answer (score 3):

I created a view like this to get last date by the subscriber

```
select subscriber_name, max(start_time) as last_sync 
from msMerge_sessions inner join msMerge_agents 
   on msmerge_agents.id = msmerge_sessions.agent_id 
group by subscriber_name
```

I called the view 'LastSync' - I then joined that view like this to get a representation similar to what the replication monitor shows.

```
SELECT     dbo.LastSync.id, dbo.LastSync.subscriber_name, dbo.LastSync.creation_date, dbo.LastSync.last_sync, 
                  distribution.dbo.MSmerge_sessions.estimated_upload_changes + distribution.dbo.MSmerge_sessions.estimated_download_changes AS estimate_rows, 
                  distribution.dbo.MSmerge_sessions.upload_inserts + distribution.dbo.MSmerge_sessions.upload_updates + distribution.dbo.MSmerge_sessions.upload_deletes + distribution.dbo.MSmerge_sessions.download_inserts
                   + distribution.dbo.MSmerge_sessions.download_updates + distribution.dbo.MSmerge_sessions.download_deletes AS actual_rows, 
                  distribution.dbo.MSmerge_sessions.duration AS total_seconds, distribution.dbo.MSmerge_sessions.percent_complete, 
                  distribution.dbo.MSmerge_sessions.delivery_rate, CASE (runstatus) 
                  WHEN 1 THEN 'Start' WHEN 2 THEN 'Succeed' WHEN 3 THEN 'In Progress' WHEN 4 THEN 'Idle' WHEN 5 THEN 'Retry' WHEN 6 THEN 'Fail' END AS Status
FROM         distribution.dbo.MSmerge_sessions INNER JOIN
                  dbo.LastSync ON dbo.LastSync.id = distribution.dbo.MSmerge_sessions.agent_id AND distribution.dbo.MSmerge_sessions.start_time = dbo.LastSync.last_sync
```

Comment: 'distribution' = Your own distribution DB for those looking wondering which variables to replace. Otherwise good one.

Answer (score 0):

For Answered Number 3

Great Effort but there're some modification On view for ability running Query

---- Create View LastSync as below

```
Create View LastSync As 
select subscriber_name, max(start_time) as last_sync, ID, creation_date
from msMerge_sessions inner join msMerge_agents 
   on msmerge_agents.id = msmerge_sessions.agent_id 
group by subscriber_name, ID, creation_date
Go
```

---- Run Below Query

> SELECT dbo.LastSync.id, dbo.LastSync.subscriber_name,
>   dbo.LastSync.creation_date, dbo.LastSync.last_sync, 
>   distribution.dbo.MSmerge_sessions.estimated_upload_changes +
>   distribution.dbo.MSmerge_sessions.estimated_download_changes AS
>   estimate_rows,  distribution.dbo.MSmerge_sessions.upload_inserts +
>   distribution.dbo.MSmerge_sessions.upload_updates +
>   distribution.dbo.MSmerge_sessions.upload_deletes +
>   distribution.dbo.MSmerge_sessions.download_inserts
>   + distribution.dbo.MSmerge_sessions.download_updates + distribution.dbo.MSmerge_sessions.download_deletes AS actual_rows, 
>   distribution.dbo.MSmerge_sessions.duration AS total_seconds,
>   distribution.dbo.MSmerge_sessions.percent_complete, 
>   distribution.dbo.MSmerge_sessions.delivery_rate, CASE (runstatus) 
>   WHEN 1 THEN 'Start' WHEN 2 THEN 'Succeed' WHEN 3 THEN 'In Progress'
>   WHEN 4 THEN 'Idle' WHEN 5 THEN 'Retry' WHEN 6 THEN 'Fail' END AS
>   Status FROM distribution.dbo.MSmerge_sessions INNER JOIN dbo.LastSync
>   ON dbo.LastSync.id = distribution.dbo.MSmerge_sessions.agent_id AND
>   distribution.dbo.MSmerge_sessions.start_time = dbo.LastSync.last_sync

-- Good Luck